# Splitting this into a x and y point?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Alright, so I'm still trying to make my players movements relative to the camera. I got a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321382?tab=votes#tab-top) But he ends it with: $s(Jx \widehat{\mathbf{x}} + Jy \widehat{\mathbf{y}}$)

So how can I turn that equation into an $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the answer you reference, $\widehat{\mathbf{x}}$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the vector from the camera to the player and $\widehat{\mathbf{y}}$ is a unit vector pointing towards the player from the camera.  Each has x and y coordinates in your coordinate plane.  $Jx$ is the x coordinate of the joystick position with a range depending on how you read it out.  Maybe it goes from 0 to 10 degrees.  Similarly for $Jy$.  So you form a new vector by multiplying and adding, then scale it by a constant $s$ that represents how fast the player should move for a given motion of the joystick.  This gives you a vector that you add to the current player position to get the new player position.

Comment: Wait, how is xˆa vector? It's just "x / |x|" which is x divided by absolute x.

Comment: But the numerator is boldface, which indicates a vector.  You have two natural coordinate systems, one with y along the axis from the camera to the player, and one the system you do all your calculations in.  He is showing you how to transform between them.